# How to make the Eureka server strong?

Tags: spring-cloud

I am new to Spring Cloud. Currently, I want to build a new micro service based on Spring Cloud. It is very easy to build a new Eureka server. But my question is that how to make it high availability ? For example I create two Eureka server and a load balancer. When one of the Eureka server is down, the system still works well. But I don't know to to consist registered information in the two Eureka server.

Comment: And another problem is that the eureka clint will send info to the eureka server in some frequently. Anyone knows how to stop that?  Because I want to upgrade my service, I have to unregister some of them and deploy the new server until there is no traffic to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I have already [asked](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud/archives/2016/09/13) something similar in the spring cloud gitter channel.

Because of the CAP theorem, something as a distributes Service discovery has to decide, either to provide availability, or more consistency, with a trade off to the other one.

in short, by quoting Spencer Gibb:

> Eureka favors availability over consistency

so it is very available, while registred services may be not acutal anymore.

As Spencer suggested, if consistency is something you need more then availability, try Consul together with spring cloud consul intead